# JQuery between limit regular expression checker?

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I write a JQuery code that test if a given variable between a given variable:

```
min
```

and a given variable:

```
max
```

also test is it alphanumeric(A-Z, a-z, 0-9) or not?

**PS:** I can check just length(I will get the value from an input field at a known id) to test between condition, which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need jquery for this problem. Just plain-old Javascript

```
function inRange(x, min, max){
   return (x >= min && x <= max);   
}
function isAlphanumeric(str){
   return  /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/g.test(str);
}

alert(inRange(50, 0, 100)); //shows true
alert(isAlphanumeric("me & you")); //shows false
```

Comment: What is the difference between ^[A-Za-z0-9]+$ and ^[A-Za-z0-9]+  ?

Comment: $ assert end of string (or line, in multiline mode)